# How to start and stop docker container with systemd

Tags: docker, systemd

I am going to leave the question with answer to help anyone who has similar problem with configuring docker and systemd together.

How we can start and stop docker container with systemd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First we will create docker image

   ```
   FROM debian:stretch

   RUN apt-get update \
       && apt-get install -y systemd \
       && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

   RUN rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/* \
       /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/* \
       /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/* \
       /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev* \
       /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl* \
       /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-tmpfiles-setup* \
       /lib/systemd/system/systemd-update-utmp*

   # systemd should be started with PID 1
   CMD [ "/lib/systemd/systemd" ]
   ```
2. Let's build our docker image

> docker build -t test_image path_to_docker_file

3. Now we can create and start new container

> docker run --name test_container -it -d --privileged --stop-signal RTMIN+3 test_image

4. Or you can start existing container

> docker start test_image

5. Now you can attach to running container to execute some bash command for example

> docker exec -it test_container bash

5. To stop container

> docker stop test_container

**IMPORTANT!!!**

Do not specify ENTRYPOINT when you start container it should be always SYSTEMD, if you want to execute something do it by attaching to container

> docker exec -it test_container bash (or other any commands)

You cannot start systemd during Docker image build.

Solution was tested for Docker version 2.0.0.3 on macOS